# Finding odd holes in circulant Paley graphs

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory

The [Paley graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley_graph) P<sub>q</sub> are those whose vertex-set is given by the [finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) GF(q), for prime powers q≡1 (mod 4), and where two vertices are adjacent if and only if they differ by a<sup>2</sup> for some a ∈ GF(q). In the case that q is prime, the finite field GF(q) is just the set of integers modulo q.

In a [recent paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2005.10.018), Maistrelli and Penman show that the only Paley graph which is [*perfect*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph) (having a chromatic number equal to the size of its largest clique) is the one on nine vertices. This implies, in particular, that none of the Paley graphs P<sub>q</sub> are perfect for q prime.

The [Strong Perfect Graph Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph_theorem#Characterizations_and_the_perfect_graph_theorems) asserts that a graph G is perfect if and only if both G and its complement lacks *odd holes* (an induced subgraph which is a cycle of odd length, and size at least 5.) The Paley graphs of prime order are self-complementary, and imperfect; therefore they must contain odd holes.

**Question.** For q≡1 (mod 4) prime, is there a poly(q) algorithm for finding an odd hole in P<sub>q</sub>? Is there a polylog(q) algorithm? Randomness and popular number-theoretic conjectures are allowed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe there is a known poly(q) algorithm. My understanding of the algorithm by Chudnovsky, Cornuéjols, Liu, Seymour, and Vušković, "Recognizing Berge Graphs", [Combinatorica 2005](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00493-005-0012-8), is that it finds either an odd hole or an odd antihole in any non-perfect graph in polynomial time. The authors write on page 2 of their paper that the problem of finding odd holes in graphs that have them remains open, because steps 1 and 3 of their algorithm find holes but step 2 might find an antihole instead. However, in the case of Paley graphs, if you find an antihole, just multiply all the vertices in it by a nonresidue to turn it into an odd hole instead.

Alternatively, by analogy to the Rado graph, for each k there should be an N such that Paley graphs on N or more vertices should have the extension property: for any subset of fewer than k vertices, and any 2-coloring of the subset, there exists another vertex adjacent to every vertex in one color class and nonadjacent to every vertex in the other color class. If so, then for k=5 you could build an odd 5-hole greedily in polynomial time per step. Maybe this direction is hopeful for a poly(log(q)) algorithm? If it works it would at least show that there are short odd holes, seemingly a necessary prerequisite to finding them quickly.

Actually, it wouldn't surprise me if the following were a poly(log(q)) algorithm: if q is smaller than some fixed constant, look up the answer, else greedily build an odd 5-hole by searching sequentially through the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, ... for vertices that can be added as part of a partial 5-hole. But maybe proving that it works in poly(log(q)) time would require some deep number theory.

By results of Chung, Graham, and Wilson, "Quasi-random graphs", Combinatorica 1989, the following randomized algorithm solves the problem in a constant expected number of trials when q is prime: if q is sufficiently small then look up the answer, else repeatedly choose a random set of five vertices, check whether they form an odd hole, and if so return it. But they don't say whether it works when q is not a prime but a prime power, so maybe you'd need to be more careful in that case.

Comment: References showing that Paley graphs do have the extension property: Paley graphs satisfy all first-order adjacency axioms
Andreas Blass, Geoffrey Exoo, Frank Harary, J. Graph. Th. 1981, and Graphs which contain all small graphs, Bollobas and Thomason, Eur. J. Combin. 1981. Unfortunately I don't seem to have subscription access to either of them so I can't say much more about what's in them.

Comment: The algorithm in [Chudnovsky+Cornuéjols+Liu+Seymour+Vušković] is actually on page 4 of the paper; but thanks for the pointer! I also find the [Cheung+Graham+Wilson] result somewhat astounding; I'll look into that.

Comment: Reading up on the [Cheung+Graham+Wilson] result: they describe on pages 359-360 that the prime-order Paley graphs are pseudo-random in their sense. If I understand correctly, your suggestion is then that all five-vertex induced labelled subgraphs (of which there are finitely many, and which of course include several specimens of 5-holes) occur approximately as often as each other; this would seem to support your description of a constant-time algorithm. I'd give +10 if I could. Many thanks!